# Create a new virtual host via php fails on Permission denied

Tags: php, apache

I have 2 problems:

1. when I run:

   `file_put_contents("/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/www.mydomain.com.conf",$vh);`

   I get the error: `failed to open stream: Permission denied`
2. How do I safely `reload` apache (after adding a domain) from PHP.
   I don't think `$res = shell_exec("sudo service apache2 reload")` is working, I dont get anything in return.

Comment: "Permission denied" i would hope so, giving php permission to write to that directory would be a bad idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its a bad practice, why don't you go and create a default virtual host that will answer to any domain.
In the app level you can do some protections about it.
This way you are shortening your code to the minimum.
He is an example (dont use it as it is, needs to be tested):

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html

    <Directory /var/www/the_site>
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
            AllowOverride All
            Order allow,deny
            allow from all
     </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 0):

You definitely do not want to do as PHP, but you might try the following approach: modify the sudoers file to grant your apache the ability to sudo a single command:

root ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /usr/local/bin/php_add_vhost

Then you create an executable script (either bash or php, python or whatever) which reads the data from a specific location, puts it in the /etc directory and does a "service apache2 reload".

This approach has many security problems, but if you are asking this question you are probably good to go anyway.